# Measuring differences in pre-/post-assessment with a "moderating" variable--which test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am running a yearlong intervention with students. I will have about 50 in my sample. Students took a pre-/post- mathematics assessment which gives them a raw score. I want to measure their growth on that assessment in comparison to the average growth of students in the school district. Also, students are taking a pre-/post-survey on their affective relationship with math. I want to run some sort of analysis that measures how the intervention influenced student test scores, using their pre-/post-survey scores as a "moderating variable" (is that the right term?). Any help on a statistical design to use?